# Keen IO - How to get a Stripe event to show with two decimals as a Keen.Number

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, keen-io

Using Keen IO (https://keen.io), I am trying to get a Stripe event to show in $X.XX format when displayed as a Keen.Number.

The result come out in pennies, so I adjusted it to dollars by dividing by 100.

It is pre-formatted to one decimal place, and I'm having trouble adding two decimal places.

Thanks in advance.

```
Keen.onChartsReady(function() {

  var revenue = new Keen.Metric(stripeEvent, {
    analysisType: "sum",
    timeframe: "this_day",
    targetProperty: "data.object.amount",
    timezone:"US/Pacific"
  });

  // Switch results from pennies to dollars
  var resultsInDollars = {}

  revenue.getResponse(function(response){
      result = response.result/100

    resultsInDollars = {
      result: result
      }

  var revenue = new Keen.Number(revenue, {
      prefix:"$",
      label:"Revenue",
    });
  // Draw number
  revenue.draw(document.getElementById("revenue"),resultsInDollars);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be a pretty easy fix!

Instead of:

```
result = response.result/100
```

try:

```
result = (Math.floor(response.result) / 100).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: It results in a perpetual "Loading..."

Comment: The perpetual loading turned out to have been an issue with the logic in our JS SDK! We're coming out with a new JS SDK soon and this definitely won't be an issue in the new SDK. We're working on fixing the current JS SDK so you can use 2 decimal points. Sorry about this!